# how to find 2nd element of stdclass object array

Tags: php, json, stdclass

i want remote html content on my page. for that i am getting an array in stdclass object array. i print_r(array) which is given below

```
stdClass Object (
     [player_video] => Array ( )
     [Title] => Ciara
     [video_Link] => Oh.flv
     [img] => img
     [desc] =>
     [view] => 18
     [artist_name] => Ciara
 )
```

how can i get title from this array. i tried `$array[0]['Title']` `$array['player_video']['Title']` but all these type of functions return nothing. i think i m using wrong approach. Please guide how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Setting `error_reporting(-1)` at the beginning would probably have showed you why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$array` seems not to be an array at all. You'll get the title attribute of this object with `$array->Title`

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow `->` instead of square brackets `[]`. Try this -

```
$array->Title
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an object then try:

```
$stdClass->Title;
```